# How to overflow my fixed footer with my drop downlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My problem is when my browser resize that the footer and my selectbox are so close enough the dropdown list is covered by the footer. I want the dropdown list overflow in my footer if they ever get close.

The purpose of onmousdown and onchange is to limit the dropdown list display if click.

```
onmousedown="if(this.options.length>7){this.size=7;}"  onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;"
```

current output: http://jsfiddle.net/GZSH6/43/

footer:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom myFooter" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="navbar-text pull-left">My Fixed Footer</p>
        </div>
</nav>
```

css:

```
.myFooter { overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, do you want something like a sticky footer? http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overflow? Did you mean overlap?

Added z-indexes, see this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YMCLJ/)**.

```
.myFooter { z-index: 1; }
.dateWrap { z-index: 2; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `z-index` property to rearrange the order of elements manually.

I edited your jsfiddle using the `z-index` property with the values 0 for the footer, and 1 for the dropdownlists.

See http://jsfiddle.net/GZSH6/43/